# What is the Account Tab under Docusign Admin?

Tags: administration, docusign

Currently all details in the account tab is set with my user. There is another user in the org who is a system admin as well in the SF org, he is not having access to all the Docusign tabs such as Status etc.

How do I add that user under admin as well in the docusign so that he also has access to all the features as of me in the Org?

Or should I just remove my details from the account tab and add that users info instead?

[image: The account tab in our org]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocuSign Account details just specify who's paying the bill, as well as API connection details. To give a user access to DocuSign features, there should be a Permission Set with the necessary features enabled. Try going to Setup > Manage Users > Permission Sets, find the appropriate DocuSign permission set, and use the Manage Assignments button to add the other user to the Permission Set.

Comment: Thank you for the info. I added the user as admin, that worked, will tryout with permission sets as well to understand more.